# Solving ModuleNotFoundError on a System with Multiple Python Versions

Tags: python, import, module

I am experiencing an issue where I am getting a ModuleNotFoundError when running a script called ConverttoWIF.py. The error message is No module named 'base58'.

When using pip freeze, the output of pip freeze is as follows:

```
altgraph==0.17.3
base58==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
dlib==19.24.0
face-recognition==1.3.0
face-recognition-models==0.3.0
future==0.18.2
numpy==1.24.1
opencv-python==4.7.0.68
pefile==2022.5.30
Pillow==9.4.0
pyinstaller==5.7.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.14
PyQt5==5.15.7
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.11.0
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
```

As you can see, I have already installed all the necessary modules.

I have also modified the PATH environment variable to include the path to the module in C:\Users\Captain\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts.

The directory contains the following files:

```
Directory of C:\Users\Captain\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts

01/04/2023  02:20 PM    <DIR>          .
01/04/2023  02:20 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/03/2023  08:44 PM           108,466 base58.exe
01/02/2023  11:58 PM           108,468 f2py.exe
01/04/2023  02:20 PM           108,486 face_detection.exe
01/04/2023  02:20 PM           108,488 face_recognition.exe
01/04/2023  01:26 PM             1,091 futurize-script.py
01/04/2023  01:26 PM            74,752 futurize.exe
01/04/2023  01:26 PM             1,095 pasteurize-script.py
01/04/2023  01:26 PM            74,752 pasteurize.exe
01/04/2023  01:26 PM           108,490 pyi-archive_viewer.exe
01/04/2023  01:26 PM           108,485 pyi-bindepend.exe
01/04/2023  01:26 PM           108,488 pyi-grab_version.exe
01/04/2023  01:26 PM           108,484 pyi-makespec.exe
01/04/2023  01:26 PM           108,487 pyi-set_version.exe
01/04/2023  01:26 PM           108,501 pyinstaller.exe
```

I also have multiple versions of Python installed on my system.

```
C:\Users\Captain>where python
C:\Users\Captain\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Users\Captain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
```

As you can see, I have both Python 3.10.9 and Python 3.11. When I run python -V, it returns "Python 3.10.9", which means it is using the Python 3.10.9 version.

Could this be the cause of the issue with my script not being able to find the base58 module? If I delete the Python 3.10.9 version, will this solve the problem? I have installed Python several times, first time via Microsoft store, python.org and probably Visual Studio.

But what confused me the most is that, I still receive the ModuleNotFoundError with the message No module named 'base58' even though I have complied the script using PyInstaller, which is supposed to include all the necessary modules in the executable. This means that I shouldn't have to worry about missing modules when running the executable on a different machine. Can someone explain why I am still encountering this error?

I hope someone out there can help me with this issue. As I'm quite new to Python, it can be intimidating and overwhelming trying to troubleshoot problems on my own. If anyone has any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve this ModuleNotFoundError issue, I would be extremely grateful. Thank you for taking the time to read my post.

I installed the necessary modules and modified the PATH environment variable, expecting the script to run without any errors. However, I encountered the ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import the base58 module.

Comment: have you created venv and install all requirements in that venv?

Comment: Yes, I used pip install virtualenv to install it. However, I received the error No module named virtualenv when I attempted to create a new virtual environment using python -m virtualenv venv.

Comment: then you missed to activate that enviroment

Comment: Have you tried using the [`py` launcher on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) ? It helps with managing versions. Also, confusingly `virtualenv` is not the same as `venv`. What I usually do (on Linux) is `python3.8 -m venv the_name_for_the_venv` to ensure I'm using the expected Python version. I suggest you try it with `py` : `py -3.10 -m venv venv_name`.